# How to bind children value to model angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the below code data is not binding between label value to input model..
if we click on div it will shows the value of children label in input model, where i tried to change label name, but two way binding is not happening between them..
[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/rknhkSaXY0k0wojwfrCn?p=preview)

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.textVal = 'click on User Name';
  
  $scope.selectedEvent = {};
    $scope.setText = function (element) {
        $scope.selectedEvent = element;
        $scope.textVal = angular.element(element.currentTarget).children('label').html();

    };
    $scope.changeLabelText = function () {
        $scope.selectedEvent.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
        angular.element(element.currentTarget).innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
    };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myapp'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    
<input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeLabelText($event)">//change user name here//
    <div ng-click="setText($event)">
      <label>User Name</label><br/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter username">
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your logic seems to be a bit off, but one thing that might get you going is the typo you made in `changeLabelText`; **angular.elhement** instead of **angular.element**

Comment: You should use [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Comment: @Matthijs i updated, can u find the sollution now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated HTML...

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeLabelText($event)">//change user name here//
<div ng-click="setText($event)">
  <label>User Name</label><br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter username">
</div>
```

Update JS

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.textVal = 'click on User Name';

 $scope.selectedEvent = {};
  $scope.setText = function (element) {
    $scope.selectedEvent = element;
    $scope.textVal =   angular.element(element.currentTarget).children('label').html();

};
$scope.changeLabelText = function () {
   // $scope.selectedEvent.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
  //  angular.elhement(element.currentTarget).innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
    angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).children('label').html($scope.textVal)
};

 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated code here...

```
   var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.textVal = 'click on User Name';

  $scope.selectedEvent = {};
$scope.setText = function (element) {
    $scope.selectedEvent = element;
    $scope.textVal = angular.element(element.currentTarget).html();

};
$scope.changeLabelText = function () {
  //  $scope.selectedEvent.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
    //angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).html($scope.textVal);

   // $scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
   angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).children('label').html($scope.textVal)
};

 });
```

HTML Updated...

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeLabelText($event)">//change user name here//
<div ng-click="setText($event)">
  <label >User Name</label><br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter username">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: but what i am telling u that,, have to show label value in input model on div click.. ur code is telling that.. have to click on label value

Comment: in that case your function will be changed as below..               $scope.changeLabelText = function () {
       // $scope.selectedEvent.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
      //  angular.elhement(element.currentTarget).innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
        angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).children('label').html($scope.textVal)
    };

Comment: uff.. Nimesh click event should be at div,, u r putting at label only.. can u please change it and tell to me, if u don't mind ..

Comment: and in the above code two way binding not happening

Answer (score 0):

Use the angular ng-model

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.textVal = 'click on User Name';
    $scope.setText = function (element) {
        $scope.textVal = 'click on User Name';
        $scope.changedVal = '';

    };
    $scope.changeLabelText = function () {
        $scope.changedVal = $scope.textVal;
    };

});
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myapp'>
  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">    
    <input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeLabelText()">//change user name here//
    <div ng-click="setText()">
      <label>User Name</label><br/> 
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter username" value="{{changedVal}}">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**If you want to update the label**

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.textVal = 'User Name';
    $scope.setText = function (element) {
        $scope.textVal = 'User Name';
    };

});
```

html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">    
    <input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeLabelText()">//change label here//
    <div ng-click="setText()">
      <i>Click here to reset</i><br/>
      <label>{{textVal}}</label><br/> 
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter {{textVal}}" value="">
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: that is good, but in ur code u have put the value of label and input value directly... but have to show label value in input tag, on div click only